# In the original IT, did IT exist or was it a figment of their imagination

Tags: it, it-1990

In the original IT movie, did Pennywise really exist or was it a figment of the protagonists imagination?
Reasons that made me believe the latter

> 1. Only they could see Penywise
> 2. Only they could see what Pennywise was doing (blood it was creating, voices etc)
> 3. Their belief that silver would harm Pennywise, actually made the earrings harm it
> 4. The asthma inhaler was just a placebo. It did not include any medicine inside. But the belief that it was battery acid, actually made the face of Pennywise melt and retreat

So did IT exist or was it a figment of the childrens imagination trying to cope with all the child murders happening during their childhood?
I mean, there is no empirical evidence that support ITs existense

**EDIT**

This is specifically about the 1990 mini-series and not the 2017 sequel/remake.

Comment: re: the inhaler, I understood it's use as a weapon to imply that water and camphor were effective against the creature, not that it was imaginary. The only thing placebo about the inhaler was that it didn't contain albuterol, not that it didn't exist at all

Comment: When you say original, do you mean the book?

Comment: @Zoredache - the question references the movie: "in the original IT movie" as well as the associated tag. Clearly the question is about the movie

Comment: If you are using "it" as a pronoun to refer to "IT" is it really a pronoun? And by "it" I mean the word "it" that is operating as a pronoun for "IT".

Comment: @Zoredache the original movie, thus the it-1990 tag

Comment: @NKCampbell Yes but it was not battery acid. And I see it as his belief it was battery acid, made the face of IT melt, Water was definitily not its weakness as it was appearing only in "watery" areas

Comment: @amflare maybe I should change everything to pennywise?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou If you did that my comment wouldn't make sense anymore xD

Comment: The 1990 version isn't a movie but a TV mini-series.

Comment: My understanding is that the IT monster is very vulnerable to the mind-states of the children. So, while real, the kids can use the "powers of their imagination" to create weapons to defeat it.

Comment: the point of my comment is that it might not matter what the kid thought was in his inhaler, the physical aspect of the chemical in said inhaler is entirely possible to have affected the creature. It wasn't just water in the inhaler but water and camphor

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Note that at least once works cross national borders, that distinction can get rather blurry. It is nice to know about the original categorization, though.

Comment: @BCdotWEB well to be honest I watched it as a one 3 hour movie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in the ~1984 view of the movie Michael Hanlon had clearly researched evidence of past killings while working as the town librarian.  He presents many news paper articles and other records from the past showing the existence of something that periodically killing people (mostly children).

Your comment and tags rule out the books, but IT(Pennywise) and the problems in Derry is mentioned in other King books like '11/22/63' and noticed by someone other then the losers club.

Comment: Did not know that Pennywise would appear in other books as well. Thank you for that. I think your answer combined with komalis comment on my question is the best combination